# Update indices in Python in a for loop (in rolling window regression)

Tags: python, indices, rolling-computation

EDIT:

I am quite new to coding and looping is still giving me a headache. What I am trying to do is to change the indices for X_train, Y_train, Y_test, Y_test by 1 step at a time in a pandas dataframe.
My dataset has 250 rows and 12 columns.

```
*For instance, in period 0 I would like to create a loop that generate intervals that looks like the intervals below:
X_train = X.iloc[0:80]
y_train = y.iloc[0:80]
X_test = X.iloc[81:]
y_test = y.iloc[81:]*

*In period 1 :
X_train = X.iloc[1:81]
y_train = y.iloc[1:81]
X_test = X.iloc[82:]
y_test = y.iloc[82:]
etc.*
```

My attempt is copied inn below:

```
**i = 0
for i in range (i,len(X)):    
    i = i + 1
    X_train = X.iloc[i:80+i]
    y_train = y.iloc[i:80+i]
    X_test = X.iloc[81+i:]
    y_test = y.iloc[81+i:]
    reg = regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(i,reg.coef_ )                   
    print(i,reg.intercept_)              
    print(i,reg.score(X_train,y_train))**
```

My preferred output is to print out coefficients, intercepts and R2 for each interval window in a regression model. 
For instance, in period 0, run a regression on the data in rows [0:80], in period 1 on rows [1:81] etc.

current error is:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 11)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestion I can get :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your question with what your desired output is, and what the current output is, its not clear to me what you want to see printed.  As a side note, you do not need to have `i = i + 1` the for loop increments `i` for you

Comment: Hi, XORNAND. I edited the whole question. The main task is to find a way to create a loop with the intervals.